# Overriding service method in grails integration test

Tags: testing, grails, groovy, metaprogramming, integration-testing

I'm trying to test controller's action in integration test. It's a simple scenario where action that I'm trying to test is calling service's method. I'm trying to override that method using metaclass but it looks like it's not working, i.e. real method of the service always getting called instead of the one that I override using metaclass. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is the controller's method:

```
class MyController {
  MyService myService

  def methodA() {
    def u = myService.find(params.paramA)
    render view: "profile", model:  [viewed: u]
  }
```

Here is how I implement integration test:

```
class MyControllerTests extends GroovyTestCase {

 MyController controller

 void testMethodA() {
    controller = new MyController()

    // Mock the service
    MyService mockService = new MyService()
    mockService.getMetaClass().find = { String s ->
      []
    }

    controller = new MyController()
    controller.myService = myService

    controller.methodA()
  }
```

P.S. I'm using grails 2.0.0 in STS 2.9.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off all I recommend to use [Spock Framework](http://code.google.com/p/spock/) which is really nice piece of testing library, besides [integrates with Grails pretty well](http://grails.org/plugin/spock).
Your test would then look like:

```
@TestFor(MyController) // TestFor is builtin Grails annotation
class MyControllerSpec extends Specification {

    // thanks to TestFor annotation you already have 'controller' variable in scope

    MyService mockService = Mock(MyService)

    // setup method is executed before each test method (known as feature method)
    def setup() {
        controller.myService = mockService
    }

    def 'short description of feature being tested'() {
        given:
        mockService.find(_) >> [] // this tells mock to return empty list for any parameter passed

        when:
        controller.methodA()

        then:
        // here goes boolean statements (asserts), example:
        controller.response.text.contains 'Found no results'
    }
}
```

If you prefer to stay without using Spock, for mock you need the simplest way will be using *Groovy coercion*. Check this out:

```
MyService mockService = [find: { String s -> [] }] as MyService
```

This is *map coercion*. In your case when mocking single method not even Map is necessary, so you can write it simpler.

```
MyService mockService = { String s -> [] } as MyService
```

This is *closure coercion*. Well, specifying the parameter is not necessary either as you are not handling it.

```
MyService mockService = { [] } as MyService
```

The last statement basically means than any method called on *mockService* will execute the specified closure, so empty list will be returned in result.

Simpler is better, cheers!

By the way, when using Spock you can still use coercion mocks. Spock mocks (created with Mock() method) are useful for testing more advanced cases, like for example interactions.

UPDATE: for integration test you would extend IntegrationSpec and no use of @TestFor will be necessary.

Comment: topr, thanks a lot! I ended up using coercion technique you suggested and everything worked just fine.

Comment: Weren't the question for integration testing? It looks like the code is for unit test.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use Grails annotation for mocking your service, as the following example taken from the documentation [10.1 Unit Testing](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html):

```
@Mock([Book, Author, BookService])
```

Then testing a controller looks like:

```
void testSearch() {
      def control = mockFor(SearchService)
      control.demand.searchWeb { String q -> ['mock results'] }
      control.demand.static.logResults { List results ->  }
      controller.searchService = control.createMock()
      controller.search()      assert controller.response.text.contains "Found 1 results"
}
```